# Set theory - Minimum Principle

Tags: induction, equivalence-relations

I would really appreciate your help with the following question,

Let us define a Preorder T over ${\mathbb R^\mathbb{R}}$ :

- ${ f T g \iff \exists h \in \mathbb R^\mathbb{R}(h \circ g = f)}$

Let ${E = T \cap T^{-1}}$ be an equivalence relation ,

we will define a new relation $T'$ over ${ \mathbb R^\mathbb{R}/E}$ :

- ${[f]_E T'  [g]_E\iff fTg }$

we will assume that $T'$ is a partially ordered set and that it is well defined,

prove that there exist Minimum and Maximum in ${<\mathbb R^\mathbb{R}, T'>}$

---

I started with induction and proved that $[m]_E$ is Min in ${<\mathbb R^\mathbb{R}}$ \  ${\{[a]_E\}, T''>}$

${T'' = \{<x,y> \in T'| x,y \in \mathbb R^\mathbb{R}}$ \  ${\{[a]_E}\}\}$

But got stuck proving that ${<[m]_E,[a]_E>\in T'}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First fix the notation. By $\langle\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}},T'\rangle$ you must have meant $\langle\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}/E,T'\rangle$, right? It doesn't need to be assumed that $T'$ is a partial order - it follows from the fact that $T$ is a preorder. And what it has to do with induction, together with the denotions you make, is a mystery at least to me...

Comment: (It's easy to state explicitly what are the minimum and maximum in this case, but I would expect to see what is the difficulty you face.)

Comment: Still write it out. The minimum is the equivalence class consisting of constant functions, and the maximum is the equivalence class consisting of bijections. The questions to be answered are (1) why these are indeed equivalence classes (i.e. elements of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}/E$) and (2) why these are indeed the minimum and the maximum respectively.